# Compute $\int_{\mathbb {R}}\sin \left(\frac {\pi x}{x^2+1}\right)\frac{1}{x^2+1} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

How do I compute this integral?
$$\int_{\mathbb {R}}\sin \left(\frac {\pi x}{x^2+1}\right)\frac{1}{x^2+1} dx$$

Comment: Since the integrand is an odd function, if the improper integral converges then the value is zero...and it does converge.

Answer (score 3):

This integral doesn't have a nice antiderivative; so, we need to think a little bit more.

Let
$$
f(x)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{x^2+1}\right)\frac{1}{x^2+1}.
$$
Notice that
$$
f(-x)=\sin\left(-\frac{\pi x}{x^2+1}\right)\frac{1}{x^2+1}=-\sin\left(\frac{\pi x}{x^2+1}\right)\frac{1}{x^2+1}=-f(x),
$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. In other words, your integrand is an *odd function*. As a result, for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$, it must be the case that
$$
\int_{-a}^{a}f(x)\,dx=0.
$$
This is not, on its own, enough to guarantee that $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\,dx=0$; however, this tells us that *if the improper integral converges, then it must be $0$*. So, it then suffices to show that the improper integral must converge.  Can you show that this integral is absolutely convergent?

Answer (score 3):

$$\left|\;\frac{\sin\frac{\pi x}{x^2+1}}{x^2+1}\;\right|\le\frac1{1+x^2}$$

and since

$$\left.\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=\arctan x\right|_{-\infty}^\infty=\pi$$

our integral converges absolutely.

But since the integrand is an odd function then the integral's value must be zero.